# Bottom View does not show in ToolbarController swift 3

Tags: swift3, cosmicmind

I'm using [ToolbarController](http://www.cosmicmind.com/material/toolbar) of [Material Framework](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material) by cosmicmind in swift 3. I have two UIViews in this controller, One is at top and other at bottom of screen. Bottom UIView does not show in Controller. I think it move down the view beyond screen.

This issue come when tested with real device. Else simulator shows correct behavior.

```
import UIKit
import Material

class RootViewController: UIViewController {
  open override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = Color.white
    prepareToolbar()
    handleTopView()
    handleBottomView()
  }

  func handleTopView() {
    let topView = UIView()
    topView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.00, y: 0.00, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 40.00)
    topView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    view.addSubview(topView)
  }

  func handleBottomView() {
    let bottomView = UIView()
    bottomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.00, y: self.view.frame.size.height, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 40.00)
    bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    view.addSubview(bottomView)
  }
}

extension RootViewController {
    fileprivate func prepareToolbar() {
      guard let toolbar = toolbarController?.toolbar else {
        return
      }

      toolbar.title = "Material"
      toolbar.titleLabel.textColor = .white
      toolbar.titleLabel.textAlignment = .left

      toolbar.detail = "Build Beautiful Software"
      toolbar.detailLabel.textColor = .white
      toolbar.detailLabel.textAlignment = .left
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are doing frame calculations in the `viewDidLoad` function and those calculations are not considering the `ToolbarController` calculations because at the point of construction for the `ToolbarController` the `RootViewController` is not connected, it is passed in as a parameter, which is after the `viewDidLoad` method is called. You can use the `Layout` API in `Material` to dynamically calculate your view's position, for example the updated code would look like:

```
import UIKit
import Material

class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = Color.white
        prepareToolbar()
        handleTopView()
        handleBottomView()
    }

    func handleTopView() {
        let topView = UIView()
        topView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        view.layout(topView).top().horizontally().height(40)
    }

    func handleBottomView() {
        let bottomView = UIView()
        bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view.layout(bottomView).bottom().horizontally().height(40)
    }
}

extension RootViewController {
    fileprivate func prepareToolbar() {
        guard let toolbar = toolbarController?.toolbar else {
            return
        }

        toolbar.title = "Material"
        toolbar.titleLabel.textColor = .white
        toolbar.titleLabel.textAlignment = .left

        toolbar.detail = "Build Beautiful Software"
        toolbar.detailLabel.textColor = .white
        toolbar.detailLabel.textAlignment = .left
    }
}
```

I tested that this works with the latest [ToolbarController sample project](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Projects/Programmatic/ToolbarController).

All the best :)

Comment: I try to reduce y origin with 40 but doesn't work now. I gradually reduce till 100. Now it is showing with this code:
`bottomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.00, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 100, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 40.00)`

Comment: Can I see how your are initializing the Toolbar?

Comment: I am using latest sample project from [ToolbarController Sample Project](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Projects/Programmatic/ToolbarController) from GitHub. The code is totally same except RootViewController that I mention above in my question. In this I just add two views. One at top and other at bottom.

Comment: I updated my answer to your question. Let me know if that helps.